# make a insert function for bracket.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, replace

I'm a making **function that replace null by another word/value**.

the var in question :

```
var saveData = {"teams":[[null,null],[null,null]]}
```

I find out that the variable is a **2D array** and to acces a null I shoud do **savedata.teams[0][0]** so i made a script that modify the variable.

```
function add(team, data) 
{
    var str = team.innerHTML;
    var str = str.replace(/<td>/g, "");
    var text = str.split("</td>");

    var i = 0;



    while(data.teams[i][0] != null || data.teams[i][1] != null)
    {
        i++;
    }

    if( i == data.teams.length - 1){}


    if(data.teams[i][0] == null)
    {
        data.teams[i][0]  = text[1];
    }
    else if(data.teams[i][0] != null)
    {
        data.teams[i][1] == text[1];
    }

    $(function() {
        var container = $('.creator')
        container.bracket({
            init: data,
            save: saveFn,
            userData: ""})
    })
}
```

the result is wierd. it output :

- first use :

  {"teams":[["team 1",null],[null,null]]}
- seconde use :

  {"teams":[["team 1",null],["team 2",null]]}

I don't know why, but I suspect **the error may come from the while** or the **if**

Comment: `data.teams[i][0] != null || data.teams[i][1] != null` if any of the two value is not null... it move to next element.... its supposed to be `data.teams[i][0] != null && data.teams[i][1] != null`

Comment: what is `team` in your function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.teams[i][0] != null || data.teams[i][1] != null` 
if any of the two value is not null... it move to next element....

its supposed to be:

```
while(i < data.teams.length)
    {
        i++;
    }



    if(data.teams[i][0] == null)
    {
        data.teams[i][0]  = text[1];
    }
    if(data.teams[i][0] != null)
    {
        data.teams[i][1] == text[1];
    }
```

Check more into logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

**Logical AND (&&)**

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

**Logical OR (||)**

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand is true.

Comment: thanks, did that but now i can only modify teams[0][0]

Comment: `if(data.teams[i][0] != null)` won't that always be true from setting it right before (unless `text[1]` is null)?

Comment: @MaximilienNowak happy to be of some help :)